# HashMap n-dimensional using a recursive function

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, hashmap, dimensions

I don't know how to make a matrix n dimensional using  HashMap.
The idea is to enter a number which indicates the dimension of the matrix and from this make a recursive function which creates the n-dimensional HashMap.

For example, if you want a 5 dimensional matrix, you have to do inside of it one with 4 dimensions, inside 3 dimensions and etc..

Comment: Could you give an example? Your question isn't quite clear. HashMap and Arrays are very different data structures. Your Map has to actually map two values together. What two values are you trying to map? Why are you trying to create a Hashmap and then create an Array from it?

Comment: Do you mean getting HashMap[]*n ?

Comment: I meant to say a n-dimensional matrix (I don't know if that's the name because english it's not my mother language).For example, if you want a 5 dimensional matrix, you have to do inside of it one with 4 dimensions, inside 3 dimensions and etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Map<List<Integer>, ValueType>
```

You can just fill your Lists that are used for the key of the map with N amount of numbers. Each number in your list specifies an offset of the dimension specified by the index of the number in your list. There is not much more to say, you can of course wrap it around and defend from "out of bounds" and such indefinite operations, which you determine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you need a recursive function for that (unless it's for learning purposes), but btw, here is what you should do :

1) The function will have 2 parameters : the current position + the dimension

2) If `(position == dimension)` then stop.

3) In the function, if `(position == 0)`, create the array.

4) In all cases, create array[position] as a new HashMap

5) Call back the function with parameters (position+1, dimension)

Hope this helps

Comment: "unless it's for learning purposes" - I suspect homework, too ...

Comment: Yes, it's for learning purposes...

Comment: That's why I didn't do the exercice for you, but instead gave you everything you need to achieve it by yourself

Comment: I'm just asking for an idea not the exercise, which is much longer.Thanks anyways.

Comment: Well then I guess my comment just gave you the "how-to" without the code, have you tried it yet?

Comment: I thought something different and i'm trying it. I hope it works! Thanks